# Not all devices that are connection via I2C are showing

Tags: i2c, bmp180, mpu6050

I have linked [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/131501739582?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) chip to my raspberry pi. I used [these](http://blog.bitify.co.uk/2013/11/interfacing-raspberry-pi-and-mpu-6050.html) instructions to do it then installed everything I was told to install using [these](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c) instructions. For some reason only two of the devices are showing when I run `sudo i2cdetect -y 0` as you can see below:

[image]

I was wondering if would explain why the third device isn't showing up (which I think is the HMC5883L chip that is not showing up).

EDIT:

Wiring diagram:

[image]

Comment: MPU6050 is 0x68 and BMP180 is 0x77. I'm not sure I understand how you are saying to work out which address HMC5883L is? :) I've also added wiring diagram to post.

Comment: @goldilocks But everything is on one chip so I can't detach individual chips.

Comment: And I linked to the other one that was working was because it had the wiring diagram :) This is the chip http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/131501739582?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: You might have a faulty board on your hands - you wouldn't by chance have purchased a second one so you can see if the issue is the same on both?

Comment: Okay, my bad.  I skipped over the first link that showed the combo breakout.  As Phil says, if two of the chips show up, obviously your wiring is right -- I dunno what else you can do.  But someone else might...

Comment: Basically, if you've got the board wired up right and _some_ of them are showing but not all, I'd say the board was faulty.

Comment: So you reckon it might be worth returning this one and buying another board? Just before I do - it isn't possible that they would have the same address?

Comment: @cross - since this is a board that has been pre-tested and packaged for commercial distribution, you would assume that that has been taken care of for you and no address conflicts exist. I would: a) contact the seller and check with them if they might have a fix for what you are seeing b) request an exchange as you think you have a faulty board c) or purchase a second board to compare if the price is not too big of a deal.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for your help. I'm going to return the board and ask for an exchange.

Comment: Try connecting ADO to ground.

Comment: @joan Which pin is ADO? There is no ADO pin on my board :)

Comment: I made the mistake of assuming the posted diagram was correct.

Comment: @joan Sorry, thats my fault. I was using that as demonstration to what I had wired. On my board I have VCC_IN, 3.3V, GND, SCL, SDA, FSYNC, INTA, DRDY. Are any of these equivalents.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.  ADO is used to set the I2C address on some modules, not yours.

Comment: @joan So in your opinion do you think it is faulty? :)

Comment: I'd be tempted to power from 5V to VCC_IN instead of 3.3V to 3.3V just as a check.  There is the (unlikely) possibility that the missing device needs 5V.  It shouldn't be a problem with I2C and the Pi.

Comment: @joan thanks for your help but sadly this didn't work.

Comment: The board you show in your wiring diagram has *only* an MPU-6050 and nothing else (save a tiny voltage regulator and support passives).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The board is not faulty, the problem is caused by the MPU6050. Add these lines to the MPU6050 initialization process:

```
self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x37, 0x02)
self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x6A, 0x00)
```

so the whole MPU6050's initialization process is something like this:

```
self.bus = smbus.SMBus(1) // or 0, depends on the revision of the board
self.address = 0x68

self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, PWR_MGMT_1, 0x80)
time.sleep(2)

...

self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x37, 0x02)
self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x6A, 0x00)
```

After running this code, type `sudo i2cdetect -y 0`, and the third device will show up.
Hope it helps!